# Can't copy files with accents to Mac OS

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu

I have server which is sharing files through SMB. Server is using Ext4 to store files.

Today I tried to copy the following file from server to Mac OS:

```
1-10 Bizet_ Carmen - Habañera.wav
```

First time it copied but I couldn't see the file itself. Second time I copied to same place and got error code -8058. After some digging I've found that for some reason this particular file is copied as link in the following way:

```
file-//localhost/Volumes/torrents-tmp/downloads/1-10%20Bizet_%20Carmen%20-%20Haban%CC%83era.wav.webloc
```

From within 100 files around 10% files are giving same problem. I'm not even able to rename it from Mac OS. If I rename `ñ` to `n` from server, then I can copy it.

Another example of such file is:

```
10 Celebración.wav
```

So it appears accents are confusing Mac OS, but I thought they are part of Unicode.

As solution to be able to copy it over, how can I mass rename all invalid files automatically?

Comment: How are you copying the files? Finder? Command line?

Comment: built in Finder, Path Finder, Disk Order.. same result.

Comment: Have you tried from the commandline?

Comment: yes. `cp: 1-10 Bizet_ Carmen - Habañera.wav: No such file or directory`

Comment: Was that with quotes? `cp "1-10 Bizet_ Carmen - Habañera.wav" /path/to`. Also, make sure that both the server and the client are using UTF8

Comment: @terdon: both with quotes and escape sequence `\`. Client is OSX which of course is using Unicode. As for the server I have successfully copied files with Chinese names for example. That suggest me the server also has no problem. It appears I need some python script which will define illegal characters and rename those... if anyone can suggest such script I would appreciate it.

Comment: I suspect the root cause of your problem is SMB. This protocol is unsuitable for use on ?NIX unless you are using an 8 bit character set. If possible install `netatalk` on the server, and connect from the Mac using Appletalk (afp:://IPaddress)

Comment: @Milliways: sorry, but unless where I am using 8 bit character set?

Comment: @pablo My comment was really related to netatalk. I have found this quite good between OSX & Linux. I haven't used SMB for years, but had lots of problems with it mangling file names - probably related to character set mapping (but maybe not 8 bit). SMB is a @!** of a protocol, with all its bus mastering issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this on the server to rename the files. It will replace all non-ascii characters with their ascii equivalent:

```
find . -type f  | 
 perl -nCAS -MText::Unidecode -e 'chomp; rename "$_", unidecode("$_");'
```

Comment: `Can't locate Text/Unidecode.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

Comment: @Pablo damn. You'll have to install the `Text::Unidecode` module. See [here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3735836/1081936) for instructions.

Comment: yeah, looks like it works. I'll check a little and get back. Installed module with `sudo apt-get install libtext-unidecode-perl` on Ubuntu.